# How to unbind all events from custom object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem is that the selectors for this object can be different.

```
$('body').on('submit','form',function(){});
$('.container').on('submit','form',function(){});
$('.container').on('submit','#myform',function(){});
```

And i don't know how to unbind all this events. 
I can use off(); function

But for each selector i can't; because there are a large number of selectors;
How i can remove each event from #myform?

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
$("#myform").children().off();
```

or you can also use `*`:

```
$("#myform *").off();
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to handle delegated handlers also

```
$("#myform").off('submit');//remove the submit handlers attached to the form
$("#myform").parents().off('submit', '#myform');//remove all submit delegated handlers registered to ancestor elements
//this is dangerous because it could remove common handlers
$("#myform").parents().off('submit', 'form');//but I don't think there is another easy way
```

Comment: Excellent man! Last question : when i use parents() i could unbind some  other forms or not (because nested forms is not possible)?

Comment: @sandra1n The only problem I could see is if there is another form in the page then if there is a common handler that could get removed

Comment: why? The ID is unique selector...what kind of handler do  u mean?

Comment: @sandra1n the handlers which used id is OK... but `$("#myform").parents().off('submit', 'form');` is a common one

Comment: why we are doing parents as well?

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad because there is no function(i dont know) that removes all events from object http://jsfiddle.net/r0xkd779/; removing events depends on selectors, and they are many

Comment: @Arun P Johny how about function bind and unbind? there are no selector at second argument -(